# Need help sending e-mail with SKU, billing address, and shipping info to dropshipper

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a product type with a term reference. This term reference lists different dropshippers. My goal is to send en e-mail to the dropshipper referenced when an order is placed.

Right now I have a rule set up to send an email to the dropshipper referenced. However, I can't seem to expose the right tokens for the email message. I need to be able to send a SKU, shipping address and the shipping info.

A few things to note:

- I am using https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_rules_extra
- Currently, I do not have a shipping module installed. I realize this data cannot be exposed at the moment.

Screenshots:

- [Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZw5l.png)
- [Component Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLbY5.png)
- [Component Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwqY0.png)
- [Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxsD0.png)
- [Available Tokens for e-mail Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Hzi.png)

Comment: Do you have the Entity Token module turned on?

Comment: @RoloDMonkey Yes, this module is enabled. I think I need to somehow expose the product and the order in this component. Just not sure how.